# Guard against infinite recursion in hook_node_load()?

Tags: 7, nodes, hooks

If I were to call the function `node_load()` inside a function implementing `hook_node_load()`, I'm assuming this would recursively trigger the `hook_node_load()` function. Is there some way of calling `node_load()` in such a way as to not trigger this hook? ...or, in `hook_node_load()`, is there some way of detecting recursive depth?

Comment: perhaps some context would help us understand the issue. What is the situation for calling node_load in hook_node_load?

Comment: BTW, does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099173/how-can-i-prevent-endless-recursion-with-drupals-node-load ?